# Why doesn't this Swift `defer` statement work as expected?

Tags: swift

I am trying to understand how the `defer` statement works in Swift 2 because I apparently do not understand it correctly.

I have a `postprocess()` method that should only be called when `view` is instantiated:

```
internal func postprocess() {
    assert(self.node.isViewInstantiated()) // <- this is failing using the first method
    ...
}
```

I was originally attempting to call it like so:

```
public var view: UIView {
    get {
        if !node.isViewInstantiated() {
            defer {
                postprocess()
            }
        }
        return node.view // node.view getter creates view
    }
}
```

But this was setting off the assert. When I changed it to this, it started working:

```
public var view: UIView {
    get {
        if node.isViewInstantiated() {
            return node.view
        } else {
            var result = node.view
            postprocess()
            return result
        }
}
```

(Note that `node.view` is self-instantiating, hence `isViewIntantiated()`.)

Can someone please explain why the `defer` doesn't actually defer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swift's `defer` keyword queues up a block to execute *when the **current** scope is exited*, which isn't necessarily the same as when the function returns.

A `defer` block inside an `if` block will be executed as you leave the scope of the `if` block.

You *could* rewrite your code as such:

```
public var view: UIView {
    get {
        let shouldPostProcess = !node.isViewInstantiated
        defer {
            if shouldPostProcess {
                postprocess()
            }
        }
        return node.view // node.view getter creates view
    }
}
```

And it should work perfectly fine.  Now the `defer`-ed block is scoped to the `get` method call and executes as it returns, where before it was scoped to the `if` block and executed as the `if` block scope exited.

Comment: I see, that definitely explains it. Unfortunately it'll be a bit tricker than simply moving the `defer` to the outside in my case, because accessing `node.view` instantiates the view, so the check to `isViewInstantiated` will always return true by that time. But I can always fix that with a Bool.